# django - отправить файл в скрипт js

Tags: javascript, python, django, файлы, jinja

Как, используя Django, минуя форму файлового менеджера, отправить файл в скрипт js, если файл хранится в переменной {{i.file}} в коде Python

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django import forms

class Task(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField('Файл',blank = False, default = '',upload_to='documents/')
    numbers = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField('Номер',blank = False, default='1')
    title =  models.CharField('Название',max_length=50, blank = False)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField( 'Дата создания',default=timezone.now,blank = False )
    status =  models.CharField('Статус',max_length=15, default="Активно", blank = False)
    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Исследование'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Исследования'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    
    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

`файл на  html странице`

```
 {% for i in tasks %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{i.numbers}}</td>
                            <td><a href="working">{{i.title}}</a></td>
                            <td>{{i.created_date}}</td>
                            <td>{{i.status}}</td>
                            <td><a href="{{i.file.url}}">{{i.file}}</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor%}
                    {% else%}
                        <p>Записей нет! Создайтей новую запись с помощью кнопки выше!</p>
                    {% endif %}
```

И получается {{i.file}} необходимо сразу отправлять в скрипт js который подключен к другой html странице
`в этот скрипт`

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files;
  if (files[0].name.includes(".nii")) {
    readNiiFile(files[0]);
  } else if (files[0].name.includes(".txt")) {
    readNameFile(files[0]);
  } else {
    readDicom(evt);
  }
}
```

как я понимаю его нужно вставлять вместо  `evt.target.files`
но js не воспринимает переменную {{i.file}}